# Setting and getting an object in a JLabel with a MouseListener

Tags: java, mouselistener

I have a `JLabel` with a `MouseListener`

```
label.addMouseListener( new ClickController() );
```

where the actions to perform are in

```
class ClickController{
...
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        // retrieve Label object
}
```

Is there any way to associate an object with the JLabel so i can access it from within the mouseClicked method?

Edit:

To give a more illustrative example, what i am trying to do here is setting JLabels as graphical representation of playing cards. The Label is intended to be the representation of an object Card which has all the actual data. So i want to associate that Card object with the JLabel.

**Solution:**

As 'Hovercraft Full Of Eels' suggest, `me.getSource()` is the way to go. In my particular case would be:

```
Card card = new Card();
label.putClientProperty("anythingiwant", card);
label.addMouseListener( new ClickController() );
```

and the get the Card object from the listener:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
   JLabel label = (JLabel) me.getSource();
   Card card = (Card) label.getClientProperty("anythingiwant");
   // do anything with card
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the clicked label from inside the mouseClicked method? If not, please elaborate.

Comment: excelent idea after update, but for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: thanks mKorbel and i will follow your advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the clicked object easily by calling `getSource()` on the MouseEvent returned in all MouseListener and MouseAdapter methods. If the MouseListener was added to several components, then clicked one will be returned this way.

i.e.,

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
   // if you're sure it is a JLabel!
   JLabel labelClicked = (JLabel) mEvt.getSource();
}
```

note: I usually prefer using the `mousePressed()` method over `mouseClicked()` as it is less "skittish" and will register a press even if the mouse moves after pressing and before releasing.

Comment: @TMichel: You're welcome! But also have a good look at JB Nizet's recommendation as it will take you further in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use a `Map<JLabel, Card>` (if you want to get a card from a label), or a `Map<Card, JLabel>` (if you want to get a label from a card).

Comment: oh, that is absolutely obvious now that you are saying :) i guess i can use both Hovercraft's and your solution depending the situation. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure, one easy way would be to create a Constructor in `ClickController` that took in a `JLabel`. Then you could access that specific `JLabel` within the object. For example:

```
class ClickController{
    private JLabel label;
    public ClickController(JLabel label){
        this.label = label;
    }    ...
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        label.getText()//Or whatever you want
    }
}
```